# Footer width and text alignment

Tags: html, css, footer

What is the best width for a footer? Also how do I get the text to stay centered in the footer?  Thanks.

Comment: Also... Is their a way to make the width of the footer the exact same width as the page?

Comment: Dear see my answer for demo and let me if any issue or i am lagging some where..

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I was looking for! (I think at least).  Thanks to all that responded for your help!

Comment: If my answer is correct then accept it so in future if some one get the same issue he/she can get the correct answer. please.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new... Did I do it right?

Comment: Ohh first of welcome to community my dear and secondly i apologize i dint see that you recently join the community. Thanks for accept the answer. Gud day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below fiddle for different demo:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GHEyU/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GHEyU/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

`960px` width is always suitable for monitors with resolution 1024 * 768 and above.

```
#footer{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I changed the width to 960px; but the text-align which I had, doesn't exactly center the text? Thanks for the quick replies, though.

Answer (score 0):

The width of your footer should be the same width as your page for example 960px wide. Or you can have your 960px wide footer wrapped in another div which is 100% wide giving it the appearance of a fluid footer.

```
.footer-wrapper{
width:100%
}
.footer{
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: The width should be the same width as your website, 960px is an example. You can either set it centered just under your main content or wrap it in a 100% width div and set a background the same color or style as the main footer area giving the appearance it's fluid which makes the footer stretch the whole width of the browser.